# jQuery hide parent div based on checkbox

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/p9s0pdao/

```
$("#filters :checkbox").change(function() {
    $(".listing-details > div").hide();
    $("#filters :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
        $(".listing-details ." + $(this).val()).show();
    });
});
```

Instead of hiding the .listing-details css class, I need to hide the div which starts with .wpbdp-listing

How can I go about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better to have things separated and clean: I mean we can have one function that does everything, thus we can call it anytime we wish. I mean calling it after `DOM` loads, and next when checkboxes change.

```
ToggleThings();

$("#filters :checkbox").change(function() {
    ToggleThings();
});

function ToggleThings()
{
    $(".wpbdp-listing").hide();
    $("#filters :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
        $('.' + $(this).val()).closest('.wpbdp-listing').show();
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p9s0pdao/1/

**Update (*final solution*):**

```
ToggleThings();

$("#filters :checkbox").change(function() {
    ToggleThings();
});

function ToggleThings()
{
    var checkedboxes = $("#filters :checkbox:checked");

    if (checkedboxes.length > 0)
    {
        $(".wpbdp-listing:visible").hide();

        checkedboxes.each(function() {
            $('.' + $(this).val()).closest('.wpbdp-listing').show();
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $(".wpbdp-listing").show();
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p9s0pdao/4/

Comment: Thanks very much. How do I make it so they are all shown by default, and all shown when no checkboxes are selected?

Comment: you can comment first line, so they will be shown at start

Comment: Also you can execute this: `$(".wpbdp-listing").show();` and they will shine :))

Comment: Thanks again @george-garchagudashvili I've tried adding a statement `if ($("#filters input:checkbox:checked").length > 0) { //Do nothing } else {    $(".wpbdp-listing").show(); }` But no luck? I want it to default back to displaying all of them if no checkboxes are selected.

Comment: where did you put that code? you can update my version of fiddle

Comment: I really appreciate it, works great. Now I just have to find a way for it to work with '&amp;' being the value - but that is for another thread! Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

To get the parent node no matter how deep up it is, use .closest() jquery method

```
$(".listing-details > div").closest('.wpbdp-listing').hide()
```

have a look at doc http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 2):

Try This code, Test it at [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tx5qtwq6/)

```
$(".wpbdp-listing").hide()
$("#filters :checkbox").change(function() {
        $(".listing-details ." + $(this).val()).parents('.wpbdp-listing').hide();
    $("#filters :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
        $(".listing-details ." + $(this).val()).parents('.wpbdp-listing').show();
    });
});
```

I added the " $(".wpbdp-listing").hide()" just to start it of so that the divs are hidden cuz the checkboxes are unchecked at first. you can also make it so the checkboxes are checked at first and then just remove that line.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the parent element of an element in JQuery with [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).

```
$(".listing-details").parent().hide();
```